# How to specify full .net type name in oracle coherence POF configuration?

Tags: c#, gac, oracle-coherence

I'm using oracle coherence in my C# project.
.Net project has references to Coherence and it sets some Coherence properties by 'injecting' my types. One of the examples if POF configuration:

```
<user-type>
  <type-id>1008</type-id>
  <class-name>MyTypeName, MyAssembly, version=1.2.3.4, publicKeyToken=0f73b23f05811dc2</class-name>
</user-type>
```

Even though all my types are specified by using full name with version and public key token, Coherence doesn't use it and binds to **MyAssembly**.

It's a big problem for me bacause **MyAssembly** is in GAC and binding fails. Of course I can use an application config and set:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <qualifyAssembly partialName="MyAssembly" fullName="MyAssembly,Version=1.2.3.4,publicKeyToken=0f73b23f05811dc2,culture=neutral" />
</assemblyBinding>
```

But I would like to avoid that (not every application can have a app.config - like PowerShell).

In Oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18678/net_intobjects.htm#BABJCBDD I found that:

> You need not specify a fully qualified type name within the class-name
>   element. The type and assembly name is enough.

But what if I want to specify fully qualified name?

--Edit

Right new the issue I'm having is with the **tangosol-coherence.override.xml**:

```
<security-config>
    <identity-transformer>
      <class-name>MyAssembly.IdentityTransformer, MyAssembly, Version=1.2.3.4, publicKeyToken=0f73b23f05811dc2, culture=neutral</class-name>
    </identity-transformer>
    <principal-scope>false</principal-scope>
</security-config>
```

the exception I get:

> Failed to instantiate class
>   "MyAssembly.IdentityTransformer,
>   MyAssembly, Version=1.2.3.4,
>   publicKeyToken=0f73b23f05811dc2, culture=neutral"
>   
>   MyAssembly.IdentityTransformer,
>   MyAssembly, Version=1.2.3.4,
>   publicKeyToken=0f73b23f05811dc2, culture=neutral

in **Assembly Binding Log Viewer**:

> WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly: WRN:
>   Assembly Name: MyAssembly, Version=1.2.3.4 | Domain ID: 1
>
> Calling assembly : Coherence, Version=3.7.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ada89708fdf1f9a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that issue by analysing Coherence disassembled dll.

It looks like:

```
Tangosol.Util.TypeResolver.Resolve(typeName);
```

cannot resolve type when it specified like this:

```
MyAssembly.IdentityTransformer, MyAssembly, Version=1.2.3.4, publicKeyToken=0f73b23f05811dc2, culture=neutral
```

but it can when it's specified like this:

```
MyAssembly.IdentityTransformer, MyAssembly, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0f73b23f05811dc2
```

So modyfing the **tangosol-coherence.override.xml** fixed it.